# Show restriction map is a contraction/lipschitz mapping

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

> For $C[a,b]$ (set of all continuous real valued functions), define
>   $d(f,g) = \int^{b}_{a}|f(x)-g(x)|dx$
>
> If $[c,d]$ is a subinterval of $[a,b]$ and the mapping $r:C[a,b]
>  \rightarrow C[c,d]$
>
> is defined as $ r:f \rightarrow r(f) = f|_{[c,d]}$
>
> Where on $C[c,d]$ the metric is defined similarly: $d'(f,g) =
>  \int^{d}_{c}|f(x)-g(x)|dx$
>
> Show that $r$ is a lipschitz mapping.

To show that this is a lipschitz/contraction mapping, I need to show:
$$d(f,g) = Kd'(f,g)$$ where $ 0<K<1$

If I understand this correctly, this should be pretty straightforward right?

Since $[c,d]$ is a subinterval of $[a,b]$

$$ \implies    \frac{\int^{d}_{c}|f(x)-g(x)|dx }{ \int^{b}_{a}|f(x)-g(x)|dx } < 1$$

$$ \implies    \frac{\int^{d}_{c}|f(x)-g(x)|dx }{ \int^{b}_{a}|f(x)-g(x)|dx } \le K$$
 for some $0<K<1$

Hence, $r$ is a contraction mapping.

Do I need to know explicitly what $K$ is? Or simply that such $K$ must exist?

Comment: The restriction map is not a contraction (unless $c = d$). You seem to think that Lipschitz and contraction are the same thing, but they aren't. Contractions are Lipschitz maps with Lipschitz constant $< 1$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I have looked further into the definitions to clarify. If I just wanted to show the mapping is Lipschitz - then would it simply be that $r$ is lipschitz with $K=1$?

Comment: Right. And $K = 1$ is sharp, unless the interval $[c,d]$ is degenerate, in which case you can take $K = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Surely $d'(r(f),r(g)) \leq d(f,g)$ (so $r$ is Lipschitz with $K=1$). This is straightforward, since
$$\int_a^b (\mbox{ something } \ge 0) \ge \int_c^d (\mbox{ the same thing } \ge 0)$$
(I hope my notation is clear)

You cannot find $K < 1$, since there exist some non-zero functions with support inside $[c,d]$. For such functions $f$ you have
$$d'(r(f),r(0)) = \int_c^d |f(t)-0(t)|dt = \int_a^b |f(t)-0(t)|dt = d(f,0)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have looked further into the definitions - understand that contraction and lipschitz is not the same thing. However, I'm a bit confused with the example you have given - what exactly is the function $0(t)$? Is it the zero function? I'm not understanding how the right integral is not greater than the left. Thanks.

Comment: $0(t)$ denotes the zero function, while $f$ denotes a non-zero function vanishing outside the subinterval $[c,d]$. In this case the two integrals are equal, since outside $[c,d]$ the integrand is $0$.

Comment: But then wouldn't we have $\int^d_{c} |f(t)|dt$ and $\int^b_{a} |f(t)|dt$? Why would the latter integral not still be greater than the first?

Answer (score 0):

i do not think that there is such a k! We take [a,b]=[0,2],[c,d]=[0,1] and construct a sequence of mappings f_n such that I_1/I_1'=1/2,I_2/I_2'=2/3,I_3/I_3'=3/4,.... Here we mean by I_n the integral of (f_n-0) over [0,2] and I_n' to be the integral of (f_n-0) over [0,1]. When we divide we get a sequence approaching 1  and so we cannot say k=1.